# Angular form to screen

Tags: javascript, angularjs, forms

I can seem to find a solution for this, as its not outputting the form data

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.update = function(person){
        $scope.club = angular.copy($scope.person);
    };

}]);
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/2ykgjmfs/

Comment: It would help if we could see the form logic

Answer (score 0):

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {

    $scope.person = {};
    $scope.club = [];

    $scope.update = function(person){
        $scope.club.push(person);
        $scope.person = {}; // clear out the form
    };
}]);
```

or just...

```
ng-click="update()"
```

and

```
$scope.update = function() {
    // you don't need to pass the person because it's on the $scope
    $scope.club.push($scope.person);
    $scope.person = {}; // clear out the form
};
```